# DHCP Powershell sort

Tags: powershell, windows-server, dhcp

Ok, so this is more of a basic Powershell question I'm pretty sure, but here's what I am trying to do:

I am writing a quick script that reads all DHCP leases on a given scope, finds any matches for client names (in this case with 'iphone' in the name), then removes those leases from DHCP. Here's what I have so far:

```
$leases = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.1.0 | select hostname, clientid
#Find all hostnames w/ 'android' or 'iphone' in name, delete lease
$trouble = $leases | select-string -Pattern "android","iphone","ipad"
Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.1.0 -ClientId $trouble
```

The issue is that the output of $trouble now looks like this:

```
@{hostname=Someones-iPhone.domain.com; clientid=00-00-00-00-c7-cc}
```

Since I can't remove a lease based on host name (since that isn't globally unique, I assume), I need to pass the MAC, aka client ID.

How can I get the output to slim down to just have the clientid, without all the other data? I've googled my heart out, and it's not helping. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `Select-String` in order to filter by a property name - use `Where-Object`:

```
$Troubles = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ScopeId 192.168.1.0 | Where-Object {
    $_.Hostname -match "android" -or
    $_.Hostname -match "iphone"  -or 
    $_.Hostname -match "ipad"
} | Select-Object ClientId
```

If you just want the value of `ClientId`, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty ClientId`